# How to access ResourceBundle in drl file?

Tags: java, drools, resourcebundle

I am trying to use ResourceBundle inside .drl file. But its throwing an exception like

```
`java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages,     locale en_US.`
```

My code is  as follows

```
public class KnowledgeHelper {

@BeforeClass
public static KnowledgeBase getKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
    KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    String droolsRuleFilePath = System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME") + "/pp-Conf/rules/Validator.drl";
    builder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(droolsRuleFilePath), ResourceType.DRL);
    if (builder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(builder.getErrors().toString());
    }

    KnowledgeBaseConfiguration configuration = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(configuration);
    knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return knowledgeBase;
}
```

I am accessing this helper class to generate KnowledgeBase

I am creating the Knowledge session in my controller class as follows

```
knowledgeBase=knowledgeHelper.getKnowledgeBase();
        knowledgeSession = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        knowledgeSession.insert(olmvo);
        knowledgeSession.insert(validationResponse1);
        knowledgeSession.fireAllRules();
```

and my drl file is as follows

```
rule "OLM_PRODUCTION_VALIDATOR"

when
   $olm : OLMVO(workflow.code == "OLM_PRODUCTION" ,workflow_type : workflow.processKey)
   $validationResponse : ValidationResponse() 
then
    System.out.println("MESSAGE FILE-----"+EdgeAppConstant.EDGE_APP_MESSAGES_FILE);
    ResourceBundle edgeappErrorBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(EdgeAppConstant.EDGE_APP_MESSAGES_FILE);
    System.out.println("Workflow Type-----"+workflow_type);
end
```

I have imported all the classes that i'm using in this drl.

So i want to know how to access properties file directly inside .drl file.
Please Help!!

Comment: Does it work outside the DRL? Do you use absolute path to the properties or relative (if relative, is it relative to the drl path?).

Comment: My drl is outside of my war file and my properties file is in classpath. Changing the .drl outside war is wokring and we can easily  change the drl. No i use relative path for properties and is not relative to drl.

Comment: If you want to move out drl outside of war, then why don't you use guvnor. I think it would be much better..